# Accessing Userdata within Custom PermissionEvaluator

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am having some problems with my custom permissionevaluator.

I get a nullpointer exception when trying to acces userdata in `hasPermission()`

My Permission Evaluator:

```
 @Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {

    if (authentication == null) {
        System.out.println("Auth is NULL");
        return false;
    }
    User currentUser = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
    if (targetDomainObject instanceof Asset) {

        Asset currentAsset = (Asset) targetDomainObject;
        for (Role r : currentUser.getRoleList()) {
            if ("admin".equals(r.getRole())) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        //Check if owner of asset
        for (Asset a : currentUser.getAssets()) {
            if (null!=a && a.equals(currentAsset)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

The `for (Role r : currentUser.getRoleList()) {` works as expected but the line `for (Asset a : currentUser.getAssets()) {` creates a nullpointer eception

My CustomUserDetailsService:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    com.redast.model.User domainUser = getUserDAO().findByLogin(login);
    if(domainUser == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("could not find user"+login);
    }

    return new UserDAOUserDetails(domainUser);

}

private final static class UserDAOUserDetails extends com.redast.model.User implements UserDetails {

    private UserDAOUserDetails(com.redast.model.User user){
        super(user);
    }

....
}
```

The com.redast.model.User is a Entity Class whrere i am using Hibernate.

The Login:

```
public String login() {
    try {

        Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(this.getUserName(), this.getPassword());

        Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        return "/pages/unsecure/login";
    }
    return "/pages/unsecure/welcomePage?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

My guess is that the UserDAOUserDetails is not constructed correctly. I hope what I am trying to do makes sense and you can give me some insight in to fixing this issue thanks!

EDIT:

Thought my security-context.xml might be helpful:

```
 <!-- Set customUserDetailsService class as the authentication Manager for Spring Security-->
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <sec:password-encoder hash="bcrypt"></sec:password-encoder>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService"
            class="com.redast.service.CustomUserDetailsService">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="expressionHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="myPermissionEvaluator"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="myPermissionEvaluator" name="myPermissionEvaluator" class="com.redast.security.CustomPermissionEvaluator">

</beans:bean>
```

Stack:

```
Information:   09:14:14.326 [http-listener-1(4)] DEBUG     o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
Information:   09:14:14.326 [http-listener-1(4)] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@3dbdb407]
Schwerwiegend:   Error Rendering View[/pages/secure/asset.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /pages/secure/asset.xhtml @13,75 value="# {assets.currentAsset.assetTitle}": java.lang.NullPointerException
at   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
at  javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:368)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
... 92 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at   com.redast.security.CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission(CustomPermissionEvaluator.java:56)
at  org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot.hasPermission(SecurityExpressionRoot.java:136)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:112)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:85)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:11)
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPostInvocationAdvice.after(ExpressionBasedPostInvocationAdvice.java:51)
at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PostInvocationAdviceProvider.decide(PostInvocationAdviceProvider.java:38)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AfterInvocationProviderManager.decide(AfterInvocationProviderManager.java:73)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:282)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:68)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
at com.redast.service.AssetService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$32adb660.getById(<generated>)
at com.redast.managedController.AssetBean.getCurrentAsset(AssetBean.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
... 99 more
```

I am using 
Spring-security: 3.2.6.RELEASE
spring: 4.1.4.RELEASE
spring-data.jpa: 1.7.2.RELEASE
hibernate 4.3.8.FINAL

EDIT:

User Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "login")
private String login;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
// @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@Column(name = "firstName")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "lastName")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "enabled")
private Boolean enabled;

@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Role> roleList;

@JoinTable(name = "user_assets", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "users_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "assets_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Asset> assets;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userOuPK.user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<UsersOu> usersOU;

public User(User user) {
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.password);

    this.id = user.id;
    this.email = user.email;
    this.enabled = user.enabled;
    this.firstName = user.firstName;
    this.lastName = user.lastName;
    this.login = user.login;
    this.roleList = user.roleList;
    this.password = user.password;
}

public User() {
}

public User(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public User(Integer id, String login, String password) {
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
    this.id = id;
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
}

...getter and setter

}
```

UserDAO:

```
Public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{
   User findByLogin(String login);
}
```

Comment: see where exactly you are getting null pointer at this 'for (Asset a : currentUser.getAssets()) {' or at 'if (a.equals(currentAsset)) {' ?. To me It appears that you aren't populating asset property of User oject in your getUserDAO().findByLogin method, if you are trying to access currentUser.getAssets()  then currentUser must not be null.

Comment: ther exception opccures in the actual loop header. however the currentUser can not be null otherwhise the exception would have occured in the first loop (getRoleList). Asset is actually lazy loaded by hibernate (or at least should be)

Comment: I have added a null check in if condition, see if you still getting null pointer

Comment: no, exception occures in loop header. checked current user for null and is not. Added stack. perhaps i am missing something

Comment: what's there on the line 56 of CustomPermissionEvaluator.java:56?

Comment: Line 56: `for (Asset a : currentUser.getAssets()) {`  I checked currentUser and it is not NULL

Comment: everything else looks good to me your CustomPermissionEvaluator is configured properly and hasPermission is getting invoked as well, only quetion here who is raising the null pionter and from code it looks like either currentUser or the value returning from .getAssets is thrwing that? what's you getAssets returns? can you post the your user class with all required properties and methods and as well your DAO used via getUserDAO()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73913/discussion-between-bwright-and-user3247727).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks good to me your CustomPermissionEvaluator is configured properly and hasPermission is getting invoked as well, only quetion here who is raising the null pionter and from code it looks like null value returning from .getAssets() is throwing that.

Edited:
Missing

```
this.assets = user.assets;
this.usersOU = user.usersOU;
```

In the copy Constructor